# let's encrypt certificate renew after expiration

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, renewal

I'm having issues trying to renew a recently expired certificate issued with let's encrypt.
I tried launching the following commands:

```
./letsencrypt-auto renew
```

and

```
sudo ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --text --agree-tos --email dev@intuizone.com --renew-by-default --webroot --webroot-path /home/lovegistics -d lovegistics.it
```

which was the code I used to issue the certificate. Both of the command said that the certificate was succesfully renewed/issued, but it still gives me unsecure connection.
Since I was on WHM, I took a look on the manage SSL page, and it says that the certificate has actually expired yesterday.

The output for the second command:

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
- Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/lovegistics.it/fullchain.pem. Your cert will
  expire on 2016-11-20. To obtain a new or tweaked version of this
  certificate in the future, simply run letsencrypt-auto again. To
  non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
  "letsencrypt-auto renew"
```

I'm sorry, but I lost the output for the first one. Strangely, when I try to relaunch the renew command, it says that the certificates are not due for renewal yet.

How can I renew this certificate?

Thank you all in advance for your help.

EDIT: I restarted the web server (Apache) after each of these commands

Comment: Have you also restarted your web server…?

Comment: Hi, yes, i restarted it after these actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve my problem. The certificates were created successfully, but since I was on a CPanel server, they must be installed. In the following link there is an explanation directly from the cpanel team with a pearl code to copy-paste and execute when you have generated the certificate.

[cpanel forum explanation](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-installing-ssl-from-lets-encrypt.513621/)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Check certificate:

> certbot certificates

Renew command:

> certbot renew --force-renewal --cert-name api2.example.in --deploy-hook "sudo service nginx restart"

Comment: Worked perfectly on an expired cert. Can execute from any path. `--deply-hook` is optional.  Both commands also output where the certs are saved.

Answer (score 0):

have to go through a minimum number of measures to [instal Let's Encrypt SSL certificates][1].
First, by accessing active domains such as http:/yourdomain.com:2083 or http:/yourdomain.com/cpanel, go to cPanel.
When you proceed to the protection tab, the Let's Encrypt SSL icon is visible to you.
Click on the + Issue button as soon as you proceed to the Issuing a New Certificate arena.

You've got to click on your domain name then. Email the server when you're done with it. Then pick, and confirm, HTTP-01.
Click the problem button once you finish it.